# How to write a program that prompts the user to enter a number n, then prints all even squares between 1 and n

Tags: python

This is what i have so far:

```
n=int(input("Enter a number"))

for i in range (1,n+1,):

  if(i%2==0):

    print(i)
```

So for example, if the user enters 100, the program should print the following:

```
4
16
36
64
100
```

Comment: Your indentation is all wrong.

Comment: Read: [Formatting code in posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Could you post the traceback? The indentation was wrong but that could have been you pasting it in wrong.

Comment: Instead of testing whether a number is a square, just generate all the squares. And you don't need to test if a number is even, because even squares are always the square of even numbers. So just increment by 2 instead of 1.

Comment: i tried incrementing by 2 instead of 1, but it didn`t work

Answer (score 0):

The `**` operator in python acts as a power operator. So, x-squared is basically `x**2`, and `x**0.5` is square root of `x`.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number"))

for i in range(2, n**0.5+1, 2):
    print(i**2)
```

Comment: Use `range(2, n**0.5+1, 2)` so you step by 2 instead of 1. Then you don't need to test if `sqr` is even.

Comment: Easy miss, thanks for that.